# Mac only able to connect to one AirPod?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, airpods

Currently only my left AirPod is connected to my Mac and I can't figure out a way to have it recognize my right AirPod! My research suggests I need to completely reset my AirPods but I don't want to do that...

Comment: I've gone through two AirPods and they both do this; only the left one connects when I put both in. I can't believe this issue has been around for so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reset. Just connect your AirPods to another device such as your iPhone and then connect back to Mac.